# HTML/PHP File Upload

Tags: php, html, file, file-upload, upload

So i want the user to only be able  to upload docs or docx's. So first here's my html:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select a file: <input type="file" name="img">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And here's my php:

```
$allowedExts = array("doc", "docx");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    if ($extension!=".doc" || $extension!=".doc"
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

            if (file_exists("Proposals/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "Proposals/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "Proposals/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
```

Everytime I try to upload a file, whether it's a doc or a png it outputs this:

```
Upload: 
Type: 
Size: 0 Kb
Temp file: 
already exists.
```

And nothing ends up getting uploaded to the Proposals folder. So I have 2 questions:
1) what is the problem with my code?
2) it redirects to upload_file.php and displays a message. Is there a way to actually go back the main page and display text that it was successful?

Comment: Read over the example again, you are using name="img" instead of name="file" http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Don't trust the `['type']` data from the user, it can be forged. use server-side mime-type determination, but also note that .docx files are really just a .zip file that contains a pile of other files (mostly xml). Plus you're using `['name']` directly to save your file, allowing a malicious user to potentially write a file ANYWHERE on your server. In short, your script is an open invitation to pwn your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question has already been answered so I won't answer it again.

> 2) it redirects to upload_file.php and displays a message. Is there a way to actually go back the main page and display text that it was successful?

It is normally better to show the success message on the redirected page but you can solve this two ways:

- Store the previous URL (or know it) and redirect to it with `header("Location: old_page.php");`
- Make the target of the form an iframe. This means the main page itself will not redirect and you can just bubble a response from upload_file.php (which will load in the iframe) making seamless uploading for your app.

Also this is not the best way to get a file extension:

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

Try using pathinfo instead: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
$extension = pathinfo( $_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

And your `if` statement:

```
if ($extension!=".doc" || $extension!=".doc"
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
```

Even though this is a tiny usage of `in_array` I still would recommend taking that out and using a more practical method of searching arrays: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

So your `if` would become something like:

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000) && array_search($extension, $allowedExts)!==false) {
```

Comment: @AnthonyHatzopoulos Cos he didn't put my answer as his answer? My answer is quite different to his

Answer (score 4):

Your file field name is `img` and you have used `$_FILES["file"]`, but it should be `$_FILES["img"]`.

Also you need to change your if condition

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
```

There is no need of

> $extension!=".doc" || $extension!=".doc" &&

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `$_FILES["img"]`instead of `$_FILES["file"]` or rename your input name to "file".

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$extension!=".doc" || $extension!=".doc"
```

to

```
$extension!=".doc" || $extension!=".docx"
```

and use `$_FILES['img']` instead of `$_FILES['file']` because your file type is having `img` name property.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to use $_FILES["img"] array to access uploaded file properties (your "Select a file" input called "img").
2. You may use "Location" http header to redirect back to source page.