# HTML/PHP File Upload Not Receiving

Tags: php, html, iframe, file-upload, upload

So I posted an earlier question here: [upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691842/html-php-file-upload)

And I tried the solutions but now no matter if it's the correct filetype or not, it just says "invalid file". Here's my html:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="my_iframe">
    Select a file: <input type="file" name="upload">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And here's my upload_file.php:

```
$allowedExts = array("doc", "docx");
    $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["upload"]));

    if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["upload"] . "<br />";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

            if (file_exists("Proposals/" . $_FILES["file"]["upload"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["upload"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                "Proposals/" . $_FILES["file"]["upload"]);
                echo "Stored in: " . "Proposals/" . $_FILES["file"]["upload"];
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
    }
```

I've also tried:

```
$extension = pathinfo( $_FILES["file"]["upload"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

And did a

```
die($extension);
```

On both of them but *nothing* gets printed. So I have two questions
1) What is wrong with my above code
2) How do I hide the iframe until I receive a response? and then have like a okay button on it to make it go away once the user has read the response? Here's the iframe code if it helps:

```
<iframe name="my_iframe" src="upload_file.php"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$_FILES["file"]["upload"]
```

To

```
$_FILES["upload"]["name"]
```

Everywhere, and same with the other references.. So;

```
$_FILES["file"]["size"] **To** $_FILES["upload"]["size"]
```

And

```
$_FILES["file"]["type"] **To** $_FILES["upload"]["type"]
```

And

```
$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] **To** $_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]
```

Comment: Search and replace `$_FILES["file"]` with `$_FILES['upload']` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
```

It should be $_FILES["upload"]["size"] because you have

```
<input type="file" name="upload">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$_FILES["file"]["size"]
```

to

```
$_FILES["upload"]["size"]
```

and do the same for all other vars, the name attribute of your input file is **upload**, not **file**, according to your HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="upload">
                  HERE ----^
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this tutorial :
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

It should be $_FILES["upload"]
A mistake you have done