# Upload image from HyperLink auto submit

Tags: php, jquery, image, forms, upload

Here's what I have for my form right now.  It's basically an empty div with 4 links on the top right.  When the user clicks on the camera icon, I want them to be prompted to upload an image, and then uploaded once the image is selected.  Kinda the same way stackoverflow.com has this really nice form where it lets us add images, text, hyperlinks, etc.  I'm not sure how this is done.

[image]

Here's my code fort he form.

```
 echo "<form id='$box_id' name='article_box_form' method='post' action='processforms/process_techtools.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
 echo "<input name='edit_article_box_submit' type='hidden'>";
 echo "<input type='hidden' name='article_id' value='$article_id'>";    
 echo "<input type='file' id='box_image_$box_id' name='box_image_$box_id' accept='image/*' style='display:none;'>";     
 echo "<div id='$box_id' style='position:relative;padding:8px;float:left;width:100%;border:1px solid #ccc;border-radius:8px;min-height:200px;margin-top:12px;'>";
   echo "<div class='article_edit_box_btn' style='top:0px;left:650px;position:absolute;'><i class='fa fa-font'></i></div>";
   echo "<div class='article_edit_box_btn' style='top:0px;left:680px;position:absolute;'><a href='javascript:void(0);' class='add_picture'><i class='fa fa-camera'></i></a></div>";
   echo "<div class='article_edit_box_btn' style='top:0px;left:710px;position:absolute;'><i class='fa fa-arrow-down'></i></div>";
   echo "<div class='article_edit_box_btn' style='top:0px;left:740px;position:absolute;'><i class='fa fa-arrow-up'></i></div>";        
 echo "</div>";
 echo "</form>
```

";

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691842/html-php-file-upload

Comment: @drew_w no, it didn't. thanks though.

Comment: I'm stil unsure of what you are asking, are you wanting to know how to show the browser upload prompt when clicking on an image verses a normal upload button? Or are you wanting to know who to write PHP for the actual upload process?