# How to pass the content of one file upload button to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload

I am new in PHP. I have a button which upload file from system. I use javascript, when user upload file it automatically redirect to web form. On web form i use Three Fields. One is Date second is Title and 3rd is File upload button. Now i want to pass my file content to this button. is it possible?

My button which upload file

[image]

My Form after uploading file

[image]

I want to store file, date and title in db. To save the time of user i want to pass file content.

How i can do it?

Please help me

Code of Button

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script>
            function setup() {
                document.getElementById('buttonid').addEventListener('click', openDialog);
                function openDialog() {
                    document.getElementById('fileid').click();
                }
                document.getElementById('fileid').addEventListener('change', submitForm);
                function submitForm() {
                    document.getElementById('formid').submit();
                }
            }
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body onload="setup()">
        <form id='formid' action="mb.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <input id='fileid' type='file' name='filename' hidden/>
            <input id='buttonid' type='button' value='Upload MB' /> 
            <input type='submit' value='Submit' hidden="" /> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Code of my form

**mb.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

//$user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra-daily";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//$id2 = $_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT pacra_teams.title as 'teamTitle', og_users.display_name, og_users.id
FROM og_users
LEFT JOIN pacra_teams
ON pacra_teams.id = og_users.team_id
Where og_users.id = 20 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_object();

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Upload Morning Briefing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title input[type='text']").val($("#dt_title input[type='text']").attr('data-title')+dateText);
   }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
</script>

</head>
<body>

 <form action="up_mb.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div style="margin:auto; width:auto" align="center">
   <table width="547" class="tblbdr" >
    <tr>
        <td height="23"  colspan="6" class="head"><p>  Morning Briefing </p></td>
</tr>
 <tr> <td height="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Date:</b> </td> <td><input name="mydate" type="text" id="mydate" style="width:300px" readonly> </td></tr>
<tr>

<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Title: </b><br> </td> 

<td class="celltext" style="width:200px" >  <span id="dt_title"> <input name="title" type="text" value=" MB | 
<?php echo $row->teamTitle;?> | <?php echo $row->display_name; ?> | <?php echo date("d-M-y");?>" 
data-title="MB | <?php echo $row->teamTitle;?> | <?php echo $row->display_name;?> | " style="width:300px"/ readonly> </span> </td> </tr>
</tr>
<td class="celltext"><b>Upload File:</b></td>
    <td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">  
    <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" width="100%" size=80/>

   <!-- <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple style="width:300px"/> -->
   </td></tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save"/> </td> <td> </td>
    <td width="151">

   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="12">
    </td>
    <td width="290">

   </td> </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you want to store the file? What kind of database? How are you accessing the database? We need more information.

Comment: @Emz i use PHP and Mysql db. I want that when user upload file it move on my form through some variable.

Comment: @Emz please help me now

Answer (score 1):

for security reason, it's not possible to set the file of a uppload field

but you can send the file to the server with your first button and then, add information on this upload with the second form, it depends what you want to do with these data

Comment: how i can send file to the server? In my code when user upload file it redirct on Form. Can you please help me?

Comment: on the first form, you save file with the help of $_FILES and then redirect to the second form

Comment: can you give me some piece of code as a hint please

Comment: look this question, it speak both about upload and redirect : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691842/html-php-file-upload