# How to upload images as base64 to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to allow my user to upload an image using input type=file as base64 to phpmyadmin. This is what I understand so far.

```
$logosixty = new Imagick ('x');
$data = $image->getImageBlob();
$data = $mysqli->real_escape_string($data);

<form method="post">
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <div>
                <label for="clublogo">Club Logo:</label>
                <input type="file" id="img" name="img" accept="image/*">
            </div>
</form>
```

I'm trying what to find to put as x.

Comment: To upload a file using a form the `enctype` attribute for the form needs to be set as `multipart-form-data` ( unless you are using ajax of some flavour )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML/PHP File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691842/html-php-file-upload)